# What is the advantage of using proxy in network for accessing internet?

Tags: networking, proxy, port

My college has different proxies for accessing Internet like 192.168.0.2/3/4 and also a specific port number.What is the advantage of using this ? I also would like to know what exactly happens there.I also heard that my institution has different ISP connections shared over the same network. What is the role of proxy there?

Answer (score 0):

It will be very easy to know if you understand what proxies do and why they are used generally. Which could be found on a magical website called www.google.com. By using a proxy, you get more control over the network because all request go through there.Your school may want to do stuffs like traffic shaping, content filtering etc. Using the proxy server will make sure all request to the internet are routed there first.

Answer (score 0):

Proxies are good for a few things:

- Filtering.  By using a proxy, your college can filter out viruses, porn, Facebook or torrent downloads.
- Logging.  By requiring a username and password, the college can track what you do with your internet time, and can tell you off if you go somewhere you shouldn't or help you be allowing them to do traffic shaping, or other network maintenance.
- Line Bonding.  For example, if you have two ADSL lines of 5Mb, you can bond those to get a 10Mb line (normally this is done at the gateway stage, and not the proxy, but it is possible to do it at this stage of the network)
- Failover.  Again, this would normally be done at the gateway/router stage.  This detects which lines are active and routes your traffic to those lines.
- Network Connectivity.  If your college is in-turn part of a bigger academic network, this could allow crossing those network boundaries to get internet access.

Although those are valid possibilities, it's probably just for Filtering...

In the wider internet, proxies are in use for allowing access to blocked content - like giving China access to Google...